# can't import PHP class in a regular php file

Tags: php, require

I am trying to build a son api in native php. 
I created a structure with classes and now I am trying to use those classes in a regular php file that will get called from outside using an http client.

THe problem is that I can't instantiate new objects from those classes, when I do everything stops and I don't get to continue the execution of my file.

**user.php :**

```
use Actions\Users\UserMethods;

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
   try{
       $Methods = new UserMethods();

       if($_GET["id"]!==null){
           $user = $Methods->getUser($_GET["id"]);
           var_dump($user);
           echo json_encode(['user'=>$user]);
       }
   }catch (Exception $exception){
       returnError($exception->getMessage());
   }
}
```

I can vardump anything before the like  where I assign $Methods, but after I do assign nothing works.

**UserMethods Class :**

```
namespace Actions\Users;

use Models\UserModel;
use database\dbconnect;
use Constants\DbConfig;

class UserMethods
{

    private $DataBase;

    private $userValidator;

    /**
     * UserMethods constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

        try{


            $this->userValidator = new UserValidator();

            $this->DataBase = new dbconnect(DbConfig::$BD_HOST.":".DbConfig::$DB_PORT,
                DbConfig::$DB_USERNAME,DbConfig::$DB_PASSWORD,DbConfig::$DB_DBNAME);
        }catch(\Exception $exception){

            var_dump($exception);
        }
    }

    public function createUser(UserModel $userModel){
        try{
            $this->userValidator->validate($userModel);
            $name=$userModel->getName();
            $email= $userModel->getEmail();

            $sqlQuery="Insert into users(email,name) values ($$email,$$name)";
            return $this->handleQuery($sqlQuery);

        }catch(\Exception $exception){
            throw $exception;
        }
    }


    public function updateUser(UserModel $userModel){
        try{
            $this->userValidator->validate($userModel);
            $name=$userModel->getName();
            $email= $userModel->getEmail();
            $id=$userModel->getId();
            $sqlQuery="
                UPDATE users
                SET 
                    name = $$name,
                    email = $$email,
                    ...
                WHERE
                    id=$$id;
            ";
            return $this->handleQuery($sqlQuery);

        }catch(\Exception $exception){
            throw $exception;
        }
    }


    public function deleteUser($id){
        try{
            $sqlQuery="
            DELETE FROM users
            WHERE
                id=$$id;
            ";
            return $this->handleQuery($sqlQuery);

        }catch(\Exception $exception){
            throw $exception;
        }
    }

    public function getUser($id){
        try{

            $sqlQuery="
            SELECT id,name,email
            FROM users
            WHERE id=$$id
            ORDER BY id ASC
            ";
            return $this->handleQuery($sqlQuery);

        }catch(\Exception $exception){
            throw $exception;
        }
    }


    public function getAllUsers(){
        $sqlQuery="
            SELECT id,name,email
            FROM users
            ORDER BY id ASC
            ";
        return $this->handleQuery($sqlQuery);
    }


    private function handleQuery($query){
        $MysqlDb = $this->DataBase->connect();
        return $MysqlDb->query($query);
    }

}
```

What can be the problem ?

Comment: I guess there are syntax errors in the file you include.

Comment: Please configure [error reporting](https://phptherightway.com/#error_reporting) for development.

Comment: [`spl_autoload_register()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) helps a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to miss the import of the file.
When using namespaces, to make the import almost automatic, it's good to implement an autoloader, I suggest to check how to [enable autoloading using composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading)

If you have few classes you can avoid using an autoloader and just importing every class manually, in this case you should:

```
require UserMethods.php
```

at the beginning of your User.php file.

Comment: I am trying this, but composer is not an option. also, it appears I can't do something like this : `require '../../database/dbconnect.php';`

Comment: Please note that missing classes should not need to go unnoticed. If you configure error reporting for development PHP will helpfully tell you: "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Actions\Users\UserMethods' not found"

Answer (score 0):

Include autoload function or add require('pathToClass/ClassName.php') try correct path namespaces small and big letters.